# Is the “stasis” pod where the Jedi was in episode 3 of Rebels similar in function to the carbonite freezing pods?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In *Star Wars* time and again someone gets frozen in carbonite, but in that one rebels episode it was the first and only time I ever saw someone in sort of a stasis pod (albeit dead).

Now I’m wondering is this similar to a carbonite freezing or are there any differences there?

Comment: Time and again? Just how many people have been undergone carbon freezing in Star Wars?

Comment: @JohnSensebe I agree. Besides *Empire*, I can only think of a single *Clone Wars* episodes that features it.

Comment: @JohnSensebe Empire/Jedi returns, then 1 clone wars episode, then now non canon: it comes up in the star wars mmo for Tarsis, it comes up in the star wars strategy game in one of the addons,.... . So time and again additionally they seemed to be pretty sure in clone wars that it works so it is implied it is a proven method ;)

Comment: @RogueJedi see my comment above (sadly I can't double @ in one comment)

Comment: Which episode are you referring to?

Comment: @RogueJedi The Citadel" was the eighteenth episode of Star Wars: The Clone Wars television series's third season.  They seemed to be pretty sure there that it works as intended so they just HAD to know that freezing someone solid does not kill someone

Comment: @Thomas I meant which episode of *Rebels* features stasis.

Comment: @RogueJedi ah  I meant this one http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rise_of_the_Old_Masters the one dead body that was found in this episode seemed to be in sort of a stasis pod.

Comment: I always interpreted that to be some sort of execution pod. The victim surely didn't die of natural means.

Comment: Also, I imagine carbonite freezing is meant to preserve things. The victim had clearly decayed quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

**First, she wasn’t in a stasis pod.** The actual container she was in was a sarcophagus, containing her desiccated remains:

> INQUISITOR: Yes, I’m afraid Master Luminara died with the Republic. But her bones
> continue to serve the Empire, luring the last Jedi to their ends.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Rebels*, “Rise of the Old Masters”</sub>

If there were any stasis of the preservative sort, it would need to have been implemented after her body had decayed significantly, since (as mentioned in the previous quote), only bones remained. And what would have been the point?

Second, she *is* described as being in a "stasis field." **However, what’s described as a stasis field is the thing that appears to be containing her when Kanan and Ezra walk in** (though in reality the whole thing is a hologram):

> Ezra and Kanan entered the narrow cell. At the other end, a stasis
> field held a female Mirialan in prisoner’s fatigues who resembled the
> Jedi Master in the news report.
>
> “Is it really her?” Ezra asked.
>
> “Yes, but…” Kanan hesitated. “Something’s wrong.”
>
> He walked closer to Luminara and reached a hand into the field.
> “Master?”
>
> There was a charge of static, the stasis field dissolved, and Luminara
> disappeared, replaced by a skeleton floating in a sarcophagus. Kanan
> inhaled in shock. She had been a hologram.
>
> <sub>*Droids in Distress*</sub>

There’s a bit of confusion here, which Wookieepedia is helping to perpetuate. Wookieepedia claims that the coffin that Unduli was in had a stasis field that preserved her remains, in accordance with the usage of the term [in Legends.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stasis_field) This is what might lead to the misapprehension that Master Unduli’s corpse rests in a stasis pod. However, in this case, "stasis" refers to holding a living creature in place. This is how a stasis field is described in "A New Dawn":

> Sloane didn’t hit the floor, or anything else. She heard the hum in
> the air above, felt the strong pull of an invisible force holding her
> body in place. It was a stasis field, like the ones in her brig. The
> person who had pushed her walked ahead in the dark before turning and
> shining a bright portable light in her face.
>
> <sub>*A New Dawn*</sub>

In other word, the stasis field is a method of containment, not of preservation. The stasis field was a part of the hologram, to make Master Unduli’s imprisonment look convincing.

To confuse things even further, there *are* actual [stasis pods](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cryo-cycle_stasis_pod) in canon, which are generally used for short-term freezing, and can have nasty side effects.

---

As an aside: Curiously, the junior novel based on this episode refers to Luminara as being *unconscious* and inside a stasis field, despite the fact that in the episode (and indeed the picture in the book) she, or her hologram, did not appear unconscious when Kanan and Ezra walked in.

> Soon they reached Cell 0169. Inside, Master Luminara floated unconscious inside a stasis field.
>
> <sub>*The Inquisitor’s Trap*</sub>

Comment: In the episode itself there was still a glow even after the hologram disappeared so I always thought that they "preserved" her remains (there she was more or less a mumified corpsed instead of a skeleton)